# How to use MMFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer in MediaFundation.Net?

Tags: c#, directx, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I've searched in Microsoft Website about **MMFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer** but it was all written in c++. I'm trying to use MMFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer in c# but can't find any reference to how to correctly used the method.

in c++ below is the code.

```
MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), pAcquiredDesktopImage, 0, FALSE, &pMediaBuffer)
```

I tried converting the above code to c# and below is my code but seems not right because I'm getting **E_NOINTERFACE**

```
MFExtern.MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D).GUID, texture, 0, false, out buffer);
```

I'm using SharpDX DXGI and MediaFoundation.Net in my application. I'm not sure if

```
typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D).GUID
```

is Equivalent to

```
__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D)
```

Below is the wrapper for **MMFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer**

```
 [DllImport("mfplat.dll", ExactSpelling = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern HResult MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkSurface,
        int uSubresourceIndex,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBottomUpWhenLinear,
        out IMFMediaBuffer ppBuffer
    );
```

Can someone teach me how to use MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer in MediaFOundation.Net. Thanks

Edit: I used MFTrace and below is the log where it failed

```
1716,2494 03:19:20.59013 CMFTransformDetours::SetInputType @02E96B4C Failed MT: MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE=5866925327104 (1366,768);MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Video;MF_MT_FRAME_RATE=257698037761 (60,1);MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO=4294967297 (1,1);MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE=2;MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFVideoFormat_RGB32
```

Im not sure if I'm setting the input type correctly since I'm feeding the sink with direct3d surface.

Comment: The code on this thread is what I'm trying to convert in c#.using SharpDX and MediaFoundation.Net  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857680/mf-sinkwriter-memory-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your post (https://sourceforge.net/p/mfnet/discussion/711229/thread/9814e58b/#c149); I answered over there but saw your question on StackOverflow and thought I should reproduce my answer.

---

[`MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162751(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts an `IUnknown` as the second parameter, so you can pass it anything that looks like a COM object, whether native or managed. However, internally `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer` is actually looking for an object that implements the `ID3D11Texture2D` interface, which is why you have to pass the IID of that interface as the first parameter.

Your code is probably failing because you're passing in the SharpDX `Texture2D` managed object itself to `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer`. You'd think this would fail on the .NET side (i.e. compiler or marshalling error), but the .NET interop marshaller actually makes the P/Invoke function call possible. This is because any .NET class can be casted to `object`, and all .NET objects can be marshalled into a native `IUnknown` COM object via a CCW (COM callable wrapper).

The reason you're getting an `E_NOINTERFACE` from `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer` is because the .NET interop marshaller wraps the SharpDX `Texture2D` object with a native CCW, hands the CCW off to that function, and then the function tries to see if the object (which it sees as a native `IUnknown`) supports the `ID3D11Texture2D` interface. `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer` does this by using the COM `QueryInterface` function that `IUnknown` provides. However, the SharpDX `Texture2D` class does not implement the `ID3D11Texture2D` interface, so when the marshalled version of `Texture2D` is queried the lookup fails and `QueryInterface` will return `E_NOINTERFACE`.

To solve this problem you need to get the native COM pointer the SharpDX `Texture2D` is encapsulating instead of passing in the SharpDX object itself. All the SharpDX objects are derived from a base `ComObject` class that provides a `NativePointer` property accessor, which gives you an `IntPtr` to the actual wrapped COM object. This is the actual COM `ID3D11Texture2D` pointer in your case, but now we need to get an `object` out of it rather than an `IntPtr`. That looks like this:

```cs
HResult hr;
IMFMediaBuffer buffer;

// "Marshal" is from the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace

// This line converts the IntPtr texture.NativePointer in to a .NET RCW 
// (runtime callable wrapper) so that it can be used like a native .NET
// object.
object texNativeObject = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(texture.NativePointer);

// When texNativeObject is passed as an argument to MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer,
// the .NET marshaller will simply unwrap the RCW and provide a native COM 
// pointer to the function.
hr = MFExtern.MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(
    typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D).GUID, 
    texNativeObject, 
    0, false, out buffer
);

// check "hr" here for success or failure

// "COMBase" is from the MediaFoundation.Misc namespace
// If this line causes problems at runtime, just remove it. SafeRelease
// forces the .NET runtime to release the RCW now, rather than later when
// a GC happens. It calls Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...) internally.
COMBase.SafeRelease(texNativeObject); 
texNativeObject = null;
```

Alternatively, you can add another definition of `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer` that accepts an `IntPtr` as the second argument. You can add this to your own code instead of modifying MediaFoundation.NET.

```cs
class NativeMethods
{
    // EntryPoint must be provided since we are naming the alternate
    // version MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer2 to separate it from the original
    [DllImport("mfplat.dll", ExactSpelling = true, EntryPoint = "MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer")]
    public static extern HResult MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer2(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
        IntPtr punkSurface,
        int uSubresourceIndex,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBottomUpWhenLinear,
        out IMFMediaBuffer ppBuffer
    );
}
```

It's okay to use an alternate function signature like this, *only because* the `Texture2D.NativePointer` is an `IntPtr` referencing unmanaged memory. In other words, you're handing an unmanaged memory address to an unmanaged function, and that's okay.

Once you have the alternate version in your code, you can use the new `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer2` function like this:

```cs
HResult hr;
IMFMediaBuffer buffer;
hr = NativeMethods.MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer2(
    typeof(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D).GUID, 
    texture.NativePointer, 
    0, false, out buffer
);

// check "hr" here
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ozeanix for this. It is now working. But I encountered another problem and i explain it in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402898/mf-sinkwriter-write-sample-failed