# Optimizing h264 MediaFoundation encoding

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, screen-capture, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

I'm writing a screen capture application that uses the [UWP Screen Capture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).

As a result, I get a callback each frame with a `ID3D11Texture2D` with the target screen or application's image, which I want to use as input to MediaFoundation's SinkWriter to create an h264 in mp4 container file.

There are two issues I am facing:

- The texture is not CPU readable and attempts to map it fail
- The texture has padding (image stride > pixel width * pixel format size), I assume

To solve them, my approach has been to:

- Use `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource` to copy the original texture into a new one created with `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` and `D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ` flags
- Since *that* texture too has padding, create a `IMFMediaBuffer` buffer wrapping it with `MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer` cast it to `IMF2DBuffer` and use `IMF2DBuffer::ContiguousCopyTo` to *another* IMFMediaBuffer that I create with `MFCreateMemoryBuffer`

So I'm basically copying around each and every frame two times, once on the GPU and once on the CPU, which works, but seems way inefficient.

What is a better way of doing this? Is MediaFoundation smart enough to deal with input frames that have padding?

Comment: You can check this question and the answers (c# but nonetheless a good explanation) for details on how to implement hardware h264 encoding that will directly use your texture as input (as Roman suggested): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402898/mf-sinkwriter-write-sample-failed

Answer (score 1):

The inefficiency comes from your attempt to `Map` rather than use the texture as video encoder input. MF H.264 encoder, which is in most cases a hardware encoder, can take video memory backed textures as direct input and this is what you want to do (setting up encoder respectively - see D3D/DXGI device managers).

Padding does not apply to texture frames. In case of padding in frames with traditional system memory data Media Foundation primitives are normally capable to process data with padding: [Image Stride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride) and  [`MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/mf-mt-default-stride-attribute), and other [Video Format Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-type-attributes#video-format-attributes).

Comment: I am newbie plz tell me how to use texture as IMFSample ?

Comment: @user666: see [`MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatedxgisurfacebuffer), and if it is insufficient, please create a new Q with your detail.

Comment: thank you and I face new problem but I can not post new Q now.

Comment: I can not encode it to h264 and I have to encode to nv12 then to h264 right?

Comment: All Media Foundation H.264 encoders accept `NV12`. Some hardware encoders also accepr RGB32 input directly, not not all of them.

Comment: I direct ProcessInput RGB32 it gives error NOT_ENOUGH BUFFER SIZE i guess it can not accept rgb32 right?